# Sheetname in combo box userform

Tags: excel, combobox, windows-xp, excel-2010, vba

I'm looking for a way to add the sheetnames to my combobox.

Final result should be:

2 combo boxes next to each other were in the first box I can enter the sheetname and with the second box data from the sheet I just selected.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us with your attempt at this problem and where you're struggling so we can help.

Comment: Im struggling right at the start I don't know where to begin.

Comment: A fundamental understanding of Visual Basic Application programming is very helpful for beginners, you could start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx Also, please visit the [faq#questions].

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, do the following:
Starting with a new Workbook, add 2 ComboBoxes to Sheet1, then add this code to the 'ThisWorkbook' code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'iterate through all worksheets and add each one to the combobox
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Name 'add sheet name to combobox
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Then add this code to the 'Sheet1' code module:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Integer
    If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
        ComboBox2.Clear 'clear out the combobox
        'add values from A1 to A5 to ComboBox2 from selected worksheet
        For i = 1 To 5
            ComboBox2.AddItem Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("A" & i).Value
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Use the above code as a starting point, read each line and research what you don't understand until you can explain what each line does. Then you will be able to use the same concept in your solution.